# Jquery contains and clone

Tags: html, jquery

What I want here is to clone this two types of button `(submit and button)` and clone, and after cloning the original `(submit and button)` will hide.

```
<a href="" tabindex="0" type="submit" class="k-primary marker-pageToolbar-action rbs-marker-button-save k-button k-button-icon k-toolbar-last-visible" title="Save" form="theForm" id="saveButton1650346534670-Id" data-uid="e64f1b6f-b373-4708-a253-a9db4d2c9df2" data-overflow="never">Save</a>
<a href="" tabindex="0" type="button" class="marker-pageToolbar-action rbs-marker-button-saveAndNew k-button" form="theForm" id="saveAndNewButton1650348486781-Id" data-uid="80855c0d-c3cf-4078-8aaa-88bb6068956b" data-overflow="auto" style="">Save &amp; New</a>
```

jquery

```
let orgBtn = $('a:contains("Save"):first').hide()
let clnBtn = orgBtn.clone();
let orgBtn2 = $('a:contains("Save & New"):last').hide()
let clnBtn2 = orgBtn2.clone();
```

i tried also the filter function, but i dont why only one has been clone

Comment: It's bad practice to select a button based on its text content. You should assign an ID or similar to select the button. Your ```$('a:contains("Save"):first')``` selects both buttons, because both contain the text 'Save'.

Comment: Also, from looking at the jQuery documentation, ```clone()``` does not insert your elements in the DOM, it's just a stored clone. You need to use ```append()```, ```appendTo``` or similar to get your cloned element into the DOM. I suggest first working with individual IDs and seeing if your problem persists.

Comment: @Lalalena hi, but my id is always change when i refresh the page, its because of some library i used

Comment: Alright, which library are you using? There should still be an option to assign individual IDs or data attributes, at least

Comment: @Lalalena, yes i am using a framework to create a elements.

Comment: that is why i am having trouble on cloning them

Comment: You could alway try using the ```rbs-marker-button-save``` and ```rbs-marker-button-saveAndNew``` classes of your button elements to target them, if other options don't work.

Comment: @Lalalena `$('a:contains("Save"):first')` should select one button, that's what `:first` does

Comment: Note: button with `Save & New` *also* contains `Save` so the order will be important.   If you *do* append them (not shown / missing, as noted in comment above) then it will depend on *where* you append them otherwise you'll be cloning your new button instead.

Comment: **I don't know why only one has been clone[d]"* - from the code provided, you should either have both cloned or neither.    https://jsfiddle.net/t973svqp/  If you run it it again, your 1st cloned "&new" button will be hidden as that's now `:last`, so you may be confusing what's happening.   https://jsfiddle.net/t973svqp/1/   Change `& New"):last` to `& New"):first`.